# Show source and note in figure is right?

Tags: floats

I want to show the source of the image and I also want to put a note, how should I do it, I can use the 2 or just the font?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% \centering% default with `floatrow`
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\caption{A figure}
\floatfoot{A note}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Edit 1:

I search and look on the Internet about whether it is proper to put a note and a source in the image, but I only find images with one of them, whether it is a source or a note, 
Can I put both?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not clear.

Comment: @egreg i edited my question, see please

Comment: What do you mean by “a font”? Is it “source”, perhaps? Can you give an approximate idea of what you'd like to get?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "source".  Is that the path or filename of the image?  Or are you simply trying to have an image with a caption and a footnote, which seems to be what you're trying to do with your example.

Comment: @Teepeemm 
with source I refer to the origin from where I obtained such a figure, it is a reference

Comment: @egreg Off-topic clarification: In Spanish (as well as in Portuguese, for "fonte") the word "fuente" can mean both "source" and "fountain", so OP seems to have confused the translation :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to insert the source of an image. Here's one that doesn't use the `\floatfoot` feature, so it is independent of `floatrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}

\newcommand{\includegraphicswithsource}[3][]{%
  {\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
   \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\\#3
   \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% \centering% default with `floatrow`

\includegraphicswithsource[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}{Source: my basement}

\caption{A figure}
\floatfoot{A note}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]